# Weblogic: Web Service Authentication by Username Token with Digest Password

Tags: java, authentication, weblogic

I am trying to implement a simple web service, to be deployed on weblogic, with authentication by username token and a password digest.  There are a plenty of examples of code using clear text, but I could not find any examples that use digest password.

I have tried using this web service:

```
@WebService
@Policies({ @Policy( uri = "../policy/usernametoken.xml" ) } )
public class Hello{

    public String sayHello(String name){
        return "Hello : " + name;
    }
}
```

, with this WS-policy file usernametoken.xml:

```
<wsp:Policy
    xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy"
    xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" >
    <sp:SupportingTokens>
        <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/wssecuritypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
                     <sp:HashPassword />
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:UsernameToken>
        </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:SupportingTokens>
</wsp:Policy>
```

, and this client:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    HelloService service = new HelloService();
    Hello port = service.getHelloPort();

    List<CredentialProvider> credProviders = new ArrayList<CredentialProvider>();
    String username = "weblogic";
    String password = "web1ogiC";

    CredentialProvider cp = new ClientUNTCredentialProvider(username.getBytes(), password.getBytes());
    credProviders.add(cp);

    Map<String, Object> rc = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
    rc.put(WSSecurityContext.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_LIST, credProviders);
    String result = port.sayHello("xxx1");

    System.out.println("*************** RESULT from WebService ***************");
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println("******************************************************");
}
```

, but it doesn't work.

Also itryed to invoke through the SOAPUI tool with digest password, but it is also not working.

Could anyone help me by either providing a working example, or fixing my example?

EDIT: I use weblogic 12c

Comment: I have read this one 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15261_01/salt/docs11gr1/ref/sec12_assert.html#wp1073370

So it seems that weblogic 12c doesn't provide UsernameToken-token authorization with digest password